# Google Adsmob unable to display in iOS 6 devices

Tags: objective-c, ios, admob

```
- (UIView *)addbanner{
CGPoint origin = CGPointMake(0.0, 0);
self.adBanner = [[[GADBannerView alloc] initWithAdSize:kGADAdSizeBanner origin:origin]autorelease];
headerView = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320, self.adBanner.adSize.size.height)] autorelease];
self.adBanner.adUnitID = @"a14fe853330ee80";
self.adBanner.delegate = self;
[self.adBanner setRootViewController:self];
[headerView addSubview:self.adBanner];
[self.adBanner loadRequest:[self createRequest]];
return headerView;
}

- (GADRequest *)createRequest {
GADRequest *request = [GADRequest request];
AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
request.testDevices = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:appDelegate.udid, nil];
return request;
}
```

The banner only display in Simulator with iOS 6 but not device. For iOS 5, both simulator and devices did show.

I am using distribution now.

What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Check it.[image]

You are running it in test mode that's why it's not running in ios 6 device.Check the below link.
https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/best-practices

set

> request.testing = NO;

Hope it works.

Comment: nop, i tried implement adreceive and error but both return nothing. This mean the admob not even being call that why it does not show either success or fail.

Comment: I implemented it 1 months before. Code is in my home's laptop. Will back to you later

Answer (score 0):

See what they say https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/best-practices

> Test ads are not supported on iOS 6 devices; use the simulator
>   instead.

Comment: what if I want change the admob to distribution?